# Logging user's id with the query he executed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, logging

So, I am trying to log not just the postgres user but his ID from my  table (for example) Person (person_id) when he calls functions.

So far, from what I can tell I can get almost every information I need from these system tables:

- `pg_stat_activity`
- `pg_stat_statements` if I activate it (but probably won't be able to due to some restrictions)

But the part that I can't seem to figure out is if I want to log the user's ID from (for example) the User table (`user_id` for example).

Basically I'd like to create a small table that will only house the last month's log, and I will insert into it.

- user_id (not system id, but from my own table)
- IP address
- timestamptz of when he called the function/query
- query he executed

My main issue is the user_id part, since the other 3 values already exist in the `pg_stat_activity` (`client_addr`, `query_start`, `query`)

If there's no easy way to make this happen, lets say I want to create a function that will somehow select the user_id based on parameters returned by `pg_stat_activity`, but I can't seem to figure out how I would do that. Hidden table parameters like `tableoid, cmin, cmax, xmin, xmax, ctid` don't help me here, at least I don't see how, maybe I missed something?

Comment: When exactly do you want to insert a row into the log table? Which action triggers that insert?

Comment: The moment the user calls a specific function.

Comment: How is the `user_id` associated with your current session?

Comment: The function the user is calling takes his user_id parameter. So the ID value is in the function during its execution.

Comment: Then what keeps you from using it in an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: How would I bind that userid to his specific call from `pg_stat_activity`? If multiple users call the same function, what then? I need their IP address in the log table after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, the `INSERT` could look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO log (userid, clientaddr, calltime, query)
SELECT user_id,  -- function argument
       a.client_addr,
       a.query_start,
       a.query
FROM pg_stat_activity AS a
WHERE a.pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

The key to identifying the current session is the process ID of the backend process.

Answer (score 0):

pg_stat_activity has application_name. You can use that to append person_id. Before every query you can run below query

```
set application_name to my_application-<person_id>;
```

We use this way to log user_id and module from where the query was triggered. This application_name also gets logged in actual logs if you specify that in log format.